# How to solve error 'TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED' when trying with pancakeswap function swapExactTokensForETH

Tags: javascript, ethereum, smartcontracts, web3js

I am using `swapExactTokensForETH` function of pancakeswap for swapping usdt with bnb

```
var data = contract.methods.swapExactTokensForETH(
    web3.utils.toHex((Math.round(10**18)).toString()),
    web3.utils.toHex((Math.round(1 *10**15)).toString()),
    [USDTokenAddress,BNBTokenAddress],
    targetAccount.address,
    web3.utils.toHex(Math.round(Date.now()/1000)+60*20),
);
```

It's giving me the following error:

> error 'TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED

What I am missing?

Comment: You have to approve first (The token you want to exchange into ETH). Did you do it?!

Comment: yup, i got it now